# pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '') error when doing a lot of pushes to sql table

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, pymysql

I am doing a lot of inserts to a mysql table in a short period of time from python code (using pymysql) that uses a lot of different threads.

Each thread, of which there are many, may or may not end up pushing data to a MySql table.

Here is the code block that causes the issue (this can be called for each thread running):

```
        sql = ("INSERT INTO LOCATIONS (location_id, place_name) VALUES (%s, %s)")
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()          
        cursor.execute(sql, (location_id, place_name))     
        cursor.close()
```

and it is specifically this line:

```
cursor.execute(sql, (location_id, place_name))
```

That causes this error:

```
pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')
```

Note also that i define self.connection in the init of the class the above block is in. so all threads share a self.connection object but get their own cursor object.

The error seems to happen randomly and only starts appearing (I think) after doing quite a few inserts into the mysql table. It is NOT consistent meaning it does not happen with every single attempt to insert into mysql.

I have googled this specific error and it seems like it could be from the cursor being closed before running the query. but i believe it is obvious i am closing the cursor after the query is executed.

Right now I think this is happening either because of:

1. Some sort of write limit to the MySql table, although the error of pymysql.err.InterfaceError doesn't seem to say this specifically
2. The fact that I have a connection defined at a high scope that is having cursors created from in threads could somehow be causing this problem.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

seems like the issue was related to me having a universal connection object. creating one per thread seems to have removed this issue.

Answer (score 11):

I get the same problem. There is a global connection in my project code, and I find that this connection will be timed out if there is no mysql operation for a long time. This error will occur when execute sql tasks, because of the timed-out connection.

My solution is: reconnecting mysql before execute sql tasks.

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO LOCATIONS (location_id, place_name) VALUES (%s, %s)")
self.connection.ping()  # reconnecting mysql
with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:         
    cursor.execute(sql, (location_id, place_name))
```

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading to a newer PyMySQL version, I was suddenly getting the same error, but without doing a lot of queries. I was also getting an additional error:

```
[..]
pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

pymysql.err.Error: Already closed
```

Since this appears to be only real place where this error is being discussed, I'll post my solution here too.

Per the PyMySQL documentation, I was doing this:

```
connection = pymysql.connect([...])

with connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        [..]
        cursor.execute(sql)

# lots of other code

with connection:
    [...]
```

What I failed to notice is that `with connection` will automatically close the connection to the database when that context manager finished executing. So subsequent queries would fail, even though I was still able to get a cursor from the connection without error.

The solution was to not use the `with connection` context manager, but closing the database connection manually:

```
connection = pymysql.connect([...])

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    [..]
    cursor.execute(sql)

# lots of other code

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    [..]

connection.close()
```

Comment: This should be marked as the official answer. Thanks for your well written explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same error, than i found that pymysql is threadsafe, so you need to open an connection for every thread as @sometimesiwritecode said.

Source found: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/422

Answer (score 1):

dont close the connection remove the cursor.close() line should continue update your database

Answer (score 0):

For pymysql its essential to call either the connection.ping() or the cursor.connection.ping() methods to be able to continue using the connection otherwise it closes. ping() re-establishes the connection with the db/cluster and depending on whether you are trying to connect to an AWS RDS cluster you might need to pass in an argument to reconnect set to a boolean True value:

- connection.ping(reconnect=True)
  or
- cursor.connection.ping(reconnect=True)

This is right before consecutive execute() calls. Doesnt hurt to put before every execute to make sure not to fall into the same error.